# Using the Fredholm alternative to find a solvabilty condition for a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, self-adjoint-operators

I'm trying to understand how to use the Fredholm alternative to solve a system of PDEs. The specific problem is as follows

[image]

Comment: type out instead of attaching images

Comment: This is very busy, is there any way to reduce things a bit to getter get the gist? Also, "understand" is a very broad operator - what you really want to know?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use the Fredholm alternative to have a solvabilty condition on the right hand side of the first two eqn.
thank you!

Comment: Writing 'I'm trying to understand how to use the Fredholm alternative to solve this system of PDE' and then posting an image of the full problem isn't very helpful. Do you not understand the Fredholm alternative itself? Or do you not understand how to apply it to the system at hand?

Comment: I'm currently reading about the Fredholm alternative itself.
Unfortunately, I didn't encounter anything that resemble the problem that I have, so I thought maybe someone could direct me to the and give me some specific direction.

Comment: Fair enough, I had the same issue when I was learning this. I wrote a post below, but some decent material on the subject for beginners can be found in Haberman 'Applied Partial Differential Equations'. Also, you should really add more to your post about what you have tried, what you don't understand, what specifically is confusing you else this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your time and consideration.
I am familiar with asymptotic methods, but the Fredholm alternative is new to me, and I got lost in the process. I will find the book you’ve recommended for a better understanding. 
It will take some time to work through all the derivation, but at first look (and I might be wrong) it seems that the first order solution zeta_0 doesn’t satisfy equation (5) and I wonder why.
Again, thank you!

Comment: No worries. I think there is a typo in the solution they gave, there should be an $e^{y}$ multiplied against the solution as is currently written, just like in the solution for $\phi_{0}$. Then everything works.

Comment: Okay, I will check it out. One last question, could I do the same process with  
$$\phi$$ 
instead of 
$$\zeta$$

Comment: Yes, you can eliminate $\zeta$ from the system instead of $\phi$. Try it and see what happens. This will give you a different operator to $L$ thought, call it $\hat{L}$, so that you'll need to solve $\hat{L} \phi_{0} = 0$ at leading order. You will then need to compute the corresponding adjoint $\hat{L}^{*}$ and in turn find the corresponding homogeneous adjoint solution $\hat{v}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll separate this post into sections. Hopefully, by following them in the order written, you can understand how to solve systems of equations asymptotically, what solvability conditions are and how they come about. I've written this in the hope that others may also find it useful.

---

The Fredholm alternative says that, given an equation $Lu = f$, a solution to this problem exists iff $f$ is orthogonal to the homogeneous adjoint solution $v$ i.e $v$ satisfies $L^{*} v = 0$ with $L^{*}$ the adjoint operator of $L$. This is because

\begin{align} 
Lu = f \implies \langle Lu, v \rangle &= \langle u, L^{*} v \rangle \\ 
&= \langle u, 0 \rangle \\ 
&= 0 \\ &= \langle f, v \rangle \tag 1
\end{align}

for some suitable inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

---

Note that at leading order, you would have had the following problem

\begin{align} 
(1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t} \zeta_{0} - \partial_{y} \phi_{0} &= 0 \tag 2 \\ 
(1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t} \phi_{0} + (1-\Gamma \partial_{x}^{2}) \zeta_{0} &= 0 \tag 3
\end{align}

We will call this equation set $M \vec{u}_{0} = \vec{0}$ where $M$ is a matrix of derivative operators and $\vec{u}_{0} = (\zeta_{0}, \phi_{0})$. We can eliminate $\phi_{0}$ and make a single PDE by taking

$$(1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t}(2) + \partial_{y} (3) \tag 4$$

assuming the solution is regular enough to do so and to interchange derivatives, to get

$$(1+\Gamma) \partial_{t}^{2} \zeta_{0} + (1-\Gamma \partial_{x}^{2}) \partial_{y} \zeta_{0} = 0 \implies L \zeta_{0} = 0 \tag 5$$

assuming $\Gamma$ is a constant. Solving this PDE yields $\zeta_{0}$ and backsolving through $(2)$ and $(3)$ then yields $\phi_{0}$.

---

We now want to find the adjoint of $(5)$ i.e we want to find $L^{*}$ such that $\langle L \zeta_{0}, v \rangle = \langle \zeta_{0}, L^{*} v \rangle$. As we are working with differential equations, we choose the inner product

$$\langle A, B \rangle = \int_{\Omega} A \bar{B} dx$$

where $\bar{B}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $B$. Computing the adjoint, using integration by parts, we find

$$L^{*} v = (1+\Gamma) \partial_{t}^{2} v - (1-\Gamma \partial_{x}^{2}) \partial_{y} v \tag 6$$

where I have assumed the evaluated terms vanish as you didn't provide the boundary conditions or even the domain. Solving $L^{*} v = 0$ fixes the homogeneous adjoint solution $v$, which we need to compute the solvability condition.

---

Finally we have all the necessary ingredients to compute the solvability condition. In your problem, at second order, you have the system

\begin{align} 
(1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t} \zeta_{2} - \partial_{y} \phi_{2} &= f_{1}(\zeta_{1}, \phi_{1}, \zeta_{0}, \phi_{0}) \\ 
(1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t} \phi_{2} + (1-\Gamma \partial_{x}^{2}) \zeta_{2} &= f_{2}(\zeta_{1}, \phi_{1}, \zeta_{0}, \phi_{0})
\end{align}

which we can write as

$$M \vec{u}_{2} = \vec{f}(\vec{u}_{1}, \vec{u}_{0}) \tag 7$$

with $M$ as before and $\vec{f} = (f_{1}, f_{2})$. As before, we apply the same operations in $(4)$ to $(7)$ to get

$$L \zeta_{2} = (1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t} f_{1} + \partial_{y} f_{2} := f \tag 8$$

In this form, hopefully you recognise why the Fredholm alternative is needed; a solution to $(8)$ exists iff $f$ is orthogonal to the homogeneous adjoint solution $v$. Therefore, provided

$$\langle (1+\Gamma)^{1/2} \partial_{t} f_{1} + \partial_{y} f_{2}, v \rangle = 0 \tag 9$$

then you can continue to compute the asymptotic solutions down further scales. Equation $(9)$ is what we call the *solvability condition* because, clearly, the system is solvable only if that condition holds. Also notice that, as the function forms of $\zeta_{1}, \phi_{1}, \zeta_{0}, \phi_{0}$ are known by this point *except for the amplitudes $A$ and $\bar{A}$*, the solvability condition $(9)$ yields an evolution equation for the amplitudes themselves.